# Add a class from ngFor

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, angular, ngfor

I have an ngFor loop and some divs inside it.
The code looks like the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of bodyElements">
   <div class="element-container">{{element.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Now I need to add a class coming from ngFor to every element produced.
So I have tried this code:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of bodyElements">
   <div class="element-container" [class]="element.className">{{element.name}}</div>
</div>
```

but now the class `element-container` is not working.
How to make both the classes work?

Comment: [class]="element.className element-container"

Comment: Throwing an errror : Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!

Comment: my bad, can you please try this, [class]="element.className + 'element-container'"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let element of bodyElements">
   <div class="element-container" [ngClass]="element.className">{{element.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ngClass to add class to any element on the basis of the condition,

The syntax is like:
[ngClass]="{className: condition}"

In your case it will be:
[ngClass]="{element.className: true}"